# How to show todays date on open flatpickr?

Tags: flatpickr

I'm trying to show todays date in flatpickr on open.
But it won't work.

This is what i tried:

```
onOpen: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) { 
        instance.set('defaultDate', 'today');
    },
```

[image]